# Various Questions about JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

i'm doing a JSF2 project.

1 . i have a form with some checkbox. Look the following code

```
<ui:repeat>
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{wagent.selectedPra}">...
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
</ui:repeat>
```

So i use selectManyCheckbox inside ui:repeat and i want that the value of the different selectManyCheckbox point to the same value.
But when the form is submit i didn't have all the selected boxs.
How i can do that ?

2 . I have a form with some inputs. On my action i want to merge some pdf files, stay on the same page and that a pop-up appear to offer to download the merged files.

3 . Does all the managed beans with request scope are created for each request or just if i used them in the xhtml page?

4 . I have a commandlink to logout. On my action i use session.invalidate() and return "login". So i go back to the login, but when validating the login, my session managed bean doesn't seem to be created. Error is something like yourSessionBean is null. What's wrong ?

Comment: I have by the way no problem with this kind of multi-questions-in-one, but in the future you should really be asking a separate question for each. That's what Stackoverflow expects from you. This allows for more fine-grained search and better matches and it also allowes for questions being better treated/closed individually (for the case it's a duplicate, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *1: So i use selectManyCheckbox inside ui:repeat and i want that the value of the different selectManyCheckbox point to the same value. But when the form is submit i didn't have all the selected boxs. How i can do that ?*

Let them point to a different value instead. With the given example the bean value will be overridden everytime until end of the loop. As an example, use a `List<List<Pra>>` in a bean (or whatever `Pra` means in your question):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{wagent.allSelectedPra}" var="selectedPra">
    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{selectedPra}">
        ...
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
</ui:repeat>
```

> *2: I have a form with some inputs. On my action i want to merge some pdf files, stay on the same page and that a pop-up appear to offer to download the merged files.*

*At least* two things needs to be done:

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().addResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=name.pdf"); // Force "Save As" dialogue.
facesContext.responseComplete(); // Prevent JSF from taking response in hands.
```

> *3: Does all the managed beans with request scope are created for each request or just if i used them in the xhtml page?*

They are created for every HTTP request. The scope which you described only applies on view scope (if I understand you right).

> *4: I have a commandlink to logout. On my action i use session.invalidate() and return "login". So i go back to the login, but when validating the login, my session managed bean doesn't seem to be created. Error is something like yourSessionBean is null. What's wrong ?*

You are probably accessing the session scoped managed bean the wrong way. You need to either inject it as `@ManagedProperty` or to grab it by `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`.

Comment: 1. How to make them point to different value. I don't know how many loops i made. 4. I acces to my session bean like that `h:commandButton action="#{mySessionBean.login}"` and he throw an error. I think that the session bean is not recreated when i logout, may be.

Comment: For 1, I've updated the answer. For 4, I need to know the exact exception/error message. This sounds more like that `yourSessionBean` is *actually* a property of another bean.

Comment: I can't post today, i will post tomorrow the exact error. You are really helpful, thanks you.